# Why Is HostPort Not Showing in The Outputs of Netstat from Host Machine

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl

I used the kubectl with yaml files to create target pod, and found the process in the pod is listening target port as expected.

To my surprise, the Port is not seen in the outputs of `netstat -tunlp` or `netstat -alp` or `netstat -an` from host machine. But it works if I try telnet localhost targetPort!!!

Why this happens?? Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `docker`. By default docker does not add container network namespaces to the linux runtime data (/var/run mounted as a tmpfs from /run) which is what you see when you run the ip `netns` command.

To view the network namespaces you need to use `nsenter`.

1. Get the container id.

```
docker ps
```

2. Get the container process id.

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .State.Pid }}' <<container-id>>
```

3. Now use the nsenter to display the pods network spaces. Advantage of using `nsenter` over `docker exec` is that nsenter will enable you to execute all tools or commands available on the node inside the pod where as `docker exec` will allow only limited or restricted commands.

```
nsenter -t <<container pid>> -n netstat -tunlp
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the service on a worker node, you have to expose the pod on the worker node with a service of type [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport). Processes running inside the pods are in a different networking namespace. You can access the application from inside the pod but not from the node without the service object. See the following for ref:

```bash
$ kubectl create deploy nginx --image=nginx
$ kubectl expose deploy nginx --target-port 80 --port 80 --type NodePort
$ NODE_PORT=$(kubectl get svc nginx -ojsonpath='{ .spec.ports[0].nodePort }')
$ netstat -an | grep $NODE_PORT
tcp46      0      0  *.31563                *.*                    LISTEN     

$ curl localhost:$NODE_PORT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
...
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Since containers inside pods are running in their own network namespace therefore `netstat` is unable to detect them.

For listing ports listening inside containers use `nsenter`. This tool will help you to execute command on a different namespace of a proces (in our case PID of desired container).

1. get PID of container - SSH onto K8s worker node and run `docker inspect <containerid>` (if docker is your container runtime)

and, after grabbing PID from above command run

2. `$ nsenter -t <container-PID> -n netstat -nltp`

Answer (score 1):

```
nsenter -t <container-PID> -n netstat -nltp
```

this command show container port, not host port, still now answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Incoming connections might directly be routed into the k8s network using iptable rules (e.g. when using Calico CNI).

You can try

```
iptable -L -t nat
```

and see if your hostports turn up there.

See the explanation here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/kne734/help_demystify_hostport_networking_please/